# Function doesn't change value of the object attributes

Tags: javascript

I need to write my own set function for the object. But it does not change the value of an attribute. I call the function in another js file.

```
function parameterSet(ifFloat, variable, newValue, max){
  if(newValue >= 0 && newValue <= max){
     if(ifFloat)
        variable = newValue;   
     else
        variable = Math.floor(newValue);   
     }
 }

 exports.lightObject.prototype.changeLightStartTime = function(newValue){
     parameterSet(true, this.lightStartTime, newValue, 23);
 };
 exports.lightObject.prototype.changeLightDurationTime = function(newValue){
     parameterSet(true, this.lightDurationTime, newValue, 23);
 };

socket.on('newLightParam', function(data){    
   light.lightStartTime = data.newLightStart;           // this one works
   light.changeLightDurationTime(data.newLightLength);  // this one doesn't    
});
```

Comment: It can be for a variety of things. Provide more info.

Comment: You can't reassign the parameter to effect the object that the data was originally in. You'd have to pass the the whole `lightStartTime` object in reassign it in the `parameterSet` function, or return the new data and assign the property outside of the function call.

Comment: What's the error you are getting? And what is `light`, where does it come from/where is it defined?

Comment: There's no error, just the value of the attribute won't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because when you do that, you lose the reference to the object.
You can pass object to the function, and change **lightDurationTime** attribute inside that function.

```
function parameterSet(ifFloat, variable, newValue, max){
  if(newValue >= 0 && newValue <= max){
     if(ifFloat)
        variable.lightStartTime = newValue;   
     else
        variable.lightStartTime = Math.floor(newValue);   
     }
 }
 exports.lightObject.prototype.changeLightStartTime = function(newValue){
     parameterSet(true, this, newValue, 23);
 };
```

Or you if you want to make it more generic:

```
function parameterSet(ifFloat, variable, attribute, newValue, max){
  if(newValue >= 0 && newValue <= max){
     if(ifFloat)
        variable[attribute] = newValue;   
     else
        variable[attribute] = Math.floor(newValue);   
     }
 }
 exports.lightObject.prototype.changeLightStartTime = function(newValue){
     parameterSet(true, this, 'lightStartTime', newValue, 23);
 };  

socket.on('newLightParam', function(data){    
   light.lightStartTime = data.newLightStart;           // this one works
   light.changeLightDurationTime(data.newLightLength);  // this one doesn't    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that on the next line:

> parameterSet(true, this.lightDurationTime, newValue, 23);

`this.lightDurationTime` will be a primitive value and passed by value to the `parameterSet()` method. So, you will lost the reference to `this`. You are not passing the memory reference to a `value` as you may think. However, a simple fix, could be passing the reference to `this` and the property you want to change:

> parameterSet(true, this, "lightDurationTime", newValue, 23);

**Example:**

```js
function parameterSet(ifFloat, obj, property, newValue, max)
{
    if (newValue >= 0 && newValue <= max)
    {
        if (ifFloat)
            obj[property] = newValue;
         else
            obj[property] = Math.floor(newValue);
    }
}

var lightObject = function()
{
    this.lightStartTime = 0,
    this.lightDurationTime = 0
};

lightObject.prototype.changeLightStartTime = function(newValue)
{
    parameterSet(true, this, "lightStartTime", newValue, 23);
};

lightObject.prototype.changeLightDurationTime = function(newValue)
{
    parameterSet(true, this, "lightDurationTime", newValue, 23);
};

let light = new lightObject();
light.lightStartTime = 5;
console.log(light.lightStartTime);
light.changeLightDurationTime(10);
console.log(light.lightDurationTime);
```